# DocImgSrch error, unable to pull statements

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

I'm following the documentation, but continue to see an error.

This is the said error.

```
<FaultMsgRec>
                     <ErrCode>100</ErrCode>
                     <ErrCat>Error</ErrCat>
                     <ErrDesc>Failed to find configured message for soap action http://jackhenry.com/ws/DocImgSrch</ErrDesc>
                  </FaultMsgRec>
```

We want to pull up the Statements, maybe even 1099s, is it possible?

My input looks like the following:

```
<DocImgIdxArray>
        <DocImgIdx>
          <DocImgIdxName>ACCOUNT NUMBER</DocImgIdxName>
          <DocImgIdxType>Index</DocImgIdxType>
          <DocImgIdxValue>1881</DocImgIdxValue>
        </DocImgIdx>
      </DocImgIdxArray>
      <IdxOnly>false</IdxOnly>
      <Ver_1/>
      <DocImgFilterType>STATEMENTS</DocImgFilterType>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look on the [Jack Henry Enterprise Services Developer Portal](https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/document-image/docimgsrch/providers/), DocImgSrch is currently implemented by the following document image service providers:

- Synergy
- Hyland OnBase
- CSPI Aurora
- Proformance InfoAccess

The error that you are getting:

> ```
> <ErrDesc>Failed to find configured message for soap action http://jackhenry.com/ws/DocImgSrch</ErrDesc>
> ```

indicates that none of the service providers that are configured for the institution and environment that you are targeting (represented by InstRtId and InstEnv in the jXchangeHdr of your request) implements the API call that you are making. In other words, the jXchange Service Gateway is unable to route the DocImgSrch call to an appropriate document image service provider to handle the call.

As such, a support case will need to be opened by the financial institution through the For Clients Portal requesting the configuration of the appropriate document image service provider in jXchange. Which provider to configure will depend on the actual document image solution deployed for use by the FI (most commonly this would be Synergy). Make sure in the case to specify the environment you would like to configure the service provider in, whether it be PROD, UAT, or both.

Now with regards to your question

> We want to pull up the Statements, maybe even 1099s, is it possible?

the answer will depend on the document image provider. If it is Synergy, the answer is yes, you can pull any document type (statements, 1099s, etc.) as long as they were properly archived and you know what indexes, cabinet and predefined search filter to search on. The example you provided looks like a valid DocImgSrch request.